# Why use __stdcall for function pointer

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, stdcall

I was looking at some code like the one mentioned here: [Function pointers for winapi functions (stdcall/cdecl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970164/function-pointers-for-winapi-functions-stdcall-cdecl), [Function pointer and calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830355/function-pointer-and-calling-convention), etc.

What is the need, benefit for declaring the calling type of a function pointer as `__stdcall`?

Why declare the calling type for a function pointer at all?

Comment: Function pointers aren't very useful if you can't call the function using them.  If the compiler doesn't know what ABI the function expects, it can't call the function.

Comment: Well, create a program that declares a function as __cdecl, and declare the pointer to the function as __stdcall.  Give the function a couple of parameters (maybe and `int` and a `double`).  Create a function pointer and call the function.  Come back to SO when your program keeps crashing on the call.

Comment: See also: [What can go wrong when you mismatch the calling convention?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding a calling convention specifier in a function pointer allows you to use that calling convention when calling functions through that pointer. [__stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) is the calling convention used to call Win32 API functions.

The benefit of specifying it in a function pointer is being able to match a different calling convention according to your code's needs (e.g. when loading an external library's function via [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)). Library headers should specify them as a good programming practice.

There's a caveat though: if you embed a wrong calling convention in a function pointer, the compiler might be powerless to help you detect that and you might end up doing bad things at runtime.